# R Dataframe to File Pointer

Tags: r, io

I need to pass a list of file locations to a particular R function (it only accepts file locations). If I had all the data needed in the files imported already into dataframes, is there any way to "alias" or point to the dataframes as if they were files, and pass that to the function?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a temporary file with `tempfile()` somehow and then remove it afterwards? What does the function expect as an input file? csv? binary?

Comment: Just curious... is it an option for you to modify the function that only accepts filenames as input?

Comment: @thelatemail Good idea. This might be what I have to do. The function expects a tab-separated text file that is gzip'd.

Comment: @BillO'Brien It is possible, but would be a last resort. Since I would have to fork the code base, modify, and maintain it.